# Как отменить обновление html-элемента, который указан в Ajax-хелпере как UpdateTarget?

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

У меня есть представление, в котором есть форма для регистрации, сгенерированная с помощью хелпера Ajax.BeginForm():

```
<div id="register_form">
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Register", "Account", new AjaxOptions
   {
       HttpMethod = "POST",
       UpdateTargetId = "register_form",
       OnFailure = "onFailure",
       OnSuccess = "onSuccess",
       OnBegin = "onBegin"
   } , new { @class = "well form-horizontal" }))
   {
       // Html-код формы
   }
</div>
```

В случае успешного выполнения Ajax-запроса срабатывает скрипт onSuccess, код которого приведен ниже:

```
var onSuccess = function (result) {
    // Код обработчика
}
```

Как в скрипте onSuccess предотвратить обновление элемента с id "register_form", который указан как UpdateTarget в AjaxOptions хелпера, генерирующего форму?

Необходимо действие, аналогичное методу preventDefault().

UpdateTarget указывать в данной форме необходимо, так как от сервера может прийти как PartialView для обновления формы, так и JSON-сообщение об ошибке заполнения формы.

Answer (score 0):

Отправляйте сообщение об ошибке с кодом 400, а не 200 - и ловите его в обработчике `onError`.

Comment: Я не уточнил - ошибка не в смысле исключения, а в смысле не пройденной валидации формы на сервере. И проблема возникает, когда я возвращаю с сервера JSON-ответ, который отображаю во всплывающем сообщении, при этом происходит попытка заменить html-элемент, указанный в UpdateTargetId, из-за чего форма просто пропадает, что смотрится очень непрофессионально. Поэтому и возникает необходимость в том, чтобы отменить обновление элемента, указанного в  UpdateTarget, из метода onSuccess.

Comment: Чем ошибка в смысле исключения настолько отличается от ошибки в смысле валидации, что для второй нельзя использовать код 400?

Comment: Основная проблема не возврат сообщения об ошибке, а необходимость отменить обновление html-элемента, указанного в UpdateTargetId, если это вообще возможно.

Comment: @Nick так ведь если вернуть ошибку - он не обновится же

Comment: Mayorov, возможна ситуация, когда мне надо с сервера вернуть сообщение об успехе, которое я помещу во всплывающее окно в методе onSuccess. Если при этом передать ошибку, то на мой взгляд это будет костыль.